# Python DataFrame: Conditional Subset Based on Values in 3 Different Fields

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following Python dataframe shown below:

[image]

For each "Region" I have specific criteria for what Activities I want to show listed below:

a) For Region 1, I want to show the first three accounts with an "Activity" of meeting and the first two accounts with "Activity" of call

b) For Region 2, I want to show the first account with "Activity" of call and first account with "Activity" of meeting

c) For Region 4, I want to just show the top 6 Accounts by "Rank"

Below is the resultant dataframe I wan to get:

[image]

I can get the same number of meetings and calls by region using the code below.  But I don't know how to get a subset of different meetings and calls based on Regional criteria.

```
d1 = data[data['Activity'] == 'meeting'].groupby('Region')\
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Rank')[:3])
d2 = data[data['Activity'] == 'call'].groupby('Region')\
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Rank')[:2])    
pd.concat([d1, d2])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first image is identical to the second, I think you might need to edit it.

Comment: Yes! you are right ... made the correction

Comment: have you solved it

Answer (score 0):

I will use a naive way, just slice, then add to a blank result dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create test dataframe
a = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 1, 'meeting'],
                  ['B', 1, 2, 'meeting'],
                  ['C', 1, 3, 'meeting'],
                  ['D', 1, 4, 'meeting'],
                  ['E', 1, 5, 'call'],
                  ['F', 1, 6, 'call'],
                  ['G', 1, 7, 'call'],
                  ['H', 2, 1, 'call'],
                  ['I', 2, 2, 'call'],
                  ['J', 2, 3, 'meeting'],
                  ['K', 2, 4, 'meeting'],
                  ['L', 2, 5, 'meeting'],
                  ['M', 2, 6, 'meeting'],
                  ['N', 2, 7, 'meeting'],
                  ['O', 2, 8, 'meeting'],
                  ['P', 4, 1, 'call'],
                  ['Q', 4, 2, 'meeting'],
                  ['R', 4, 3, 'call'],
                  ['S', 4, 4, 'meeting'],
                  ['T', 4, 5, 'call'],
                  ['U', 4, 6, 'meeting'],
                  ['V', 4, 7, 'call']], columns=['Account', 'Region', 'Rank', 'Activity'])


#Create blank df
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Account', 'Region', 'Rank', 'Activity'])

temp = a[a['Region']==1] #Slice region 1
temp = temp[temp['Activity']=='meeting'].sort_values('Rank')[:3] #Slice activity meeting then sort and get first 3

result = pd.concat([result, temp]) #Add to result df

temp = a[a['Region']==1] #Slice region 1
temp = temp[temp['Activity']=='call'].sort_values('Rank')[:2] #Slice activity call then sort and get first 2

result = pd.concat([result, temp]) #Add to result df

temp = a[a['Region']==2] #Slice region 2
temp = temp[temp['Activity']=='meeting'].sort_values('Rank')[:1] #Slice activity meeting then sort and get first one

result = pd.concat([result, temp]) #Add to result df

temp = a[a['Region']==2] #Slice region 2
temp = temp[temp['Activity']=='call'].sort_values('Rank')[:1] #Slice activity call then sort and get first 1

result = pd.concat([result, temp]) #Add to result df

temp = a[a['Region']==4] #Slice region 4
temp = temp.sort_values('Rank')[:6] #Sort then get first 6

result = pd.concat([result, temp]) #Add to result df

result['Region'] = result['Region'].apply(lambda x: int(x)) #Trim result of region and rank column
result['Rank'] = result['Rank'].apply(lambda x: int(x)) #Trim result of region and rank column
```

The result would be:

```
       Account  Region  Rank Activity
0        A       1     1  meeting
1        B       1     2  meeting
2        C       1     3  meeting
4        E       1     5     call
5        F       1     6     call
9        J       2     3  meeting
7        H       2     1     call
15       P       4     1     call
16       Q       4     2  meeting
17       R       4     3     call
18       S       4     4  meeting
19       T       4     5     call
20       U       4     6  meeting
```